# restapi with feignclient + spring security 5 + oauth2.0 from custom provider

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, feign

I have read many posts and articles and documentation but I'm very confused about all this.
What I try to do is an apirest with springboot, using feignclient, and I must send a bearer token in my petitions, I get this bearer token from a custom provider.

My client class with feign looks like this:

```
@FeignClient(name="test-client", url = "https://testurl/")
public interface TestClient {
    @GetMapping("/auth/me")
    public ResponseEntity<String> testLoginInformation() throws FeignException;
}
```

my application.properties:

```
server.port=8082
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom.client-id=mylargeID
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom.client-secret=mylargePassword
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom.authorization-grant-type=client_credentials
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom.scope=access_token_only
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom.provider=custom-provider
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.custom.client-authentication-method=basic

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.custom-provider.authorization-uri=https://testurl/auth/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.custom-provider.token-uri=https://testurl/auth/token
```

In which, I think I indicate all the necesary data for making the requesto to get the token... I don't understand what is the difference between "authorization-uri" and "token-uri"

In my springboot application main class, I only have these two annotations:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
```

and last but not least important, the dependencies in my pom file look like these:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4-RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1-RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0-RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.4-RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4-RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Right now, what I'm getting is **Invalid Authorization Grant Type (client_credentials) for Client Registration with Id: custom**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you doing this in microservice ?

Comment: Yes!! That is the idea. A simple rest-api or microservice.

Comment: For me it seems that grant_type `client_credentials` is disabled.

Comment: How can I do for enable it?
Or do you refer that is disabled in the server side? When I send the request via postman, I get the response with the token.

Comment: @FranciscoPrado Solved your issue ?

Comment: @AvijitBarua No. I tried many things, OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor and RequestInterceptors, default spring security configuration,... and I can't resolve it. Probably I misunderstand something, what I think this has to do is send the requests with a bearer token that is "automatically" requested... isn't it?

Comment: @FranciscoPrado can you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

1. Authorization url

> The */authorization* endpoint is used to interact with the resource owner and get the authorization to access the protected resource. To better understand this, imagine that you want to log in to a service using your Google account. First, the service redirects you to Google in order to authenticate (if you are **not already logged in**) and then you will get a consent screen, where you will be asked to authorize the service to access some of your data (protected resources); for example, your email address and your list of contacts.

2. Token url

> An access token is an opaque string or a JWT that denotes who has authorized which permissions (scopes) to which application. It is meant to be exchanged with an access token at the */oauth/token* endpoint.

Check here for more: https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/protocol-oauth2

Comment: Thanks! If I understand well, I have to use in my application spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.custom-provider.token-uri , because I request the token to a rest api directly, no more steps.

Comment: Guys, I'm with the same problem. I'm trying to create an auth-server using AWS Cognito as provider and I want to call auth-server and the auth-server will request the token for Cognito and return. Is there something wrong in this approach?